# Occasionally Expect send command gets truncated

Tags: expect

I have an expect script that logs in to an SBC and runs a command for a particular interface.

I call this script from a shell script to perform the same command on multiple SBCs and multiple interfaces. I run the script 6 times on each SBC grabbing details for a single interface each time and the output gets saved to a different file on a per SBC/interface combination.

Trouble is, I run it for example on SBC A and in two of the files the command is truncated and nothing happens. Say interface 2 and 3.

If I run the script again, 5 interfaces work this time and now a different interface, interface 4 fails with a truncated command.

I don’t understand what would cause the command to fail randomly. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: One thing to point out, the command is always truncated at the same point.

Answer (score 0):

Ok think I have cracked it. Occasionally the command I am entering is matching the expected prompt. In reality the command should always match the prompt so strange it doesn’t fail every time.

Have tweaked the expected prompt and re-running script.